# In NODE JS Type 'ClientRequest' is missing the following properties from type 'Observable<Blob>': _isScalar, source, operator, lift, and 5 more

Tags: node.js, angular, ionic-framework, https

Getting this error in Nodejs

```
getImage(imageUrl: string): Rx.Observable<Blob> {
    return https.get(imageUrl, { responseType: 'blob' });
 }
```

How to do this nodejs call get http request for observable blob

Comment: Is that `angular` or `node.js`? Please, clarify. Also, please tell what is `https` variable here.

Comment: import https = require('https');
import Rx = require("rxjs");                            NodeJs